# Classical second quantization paper by Jordan and Wigner - ref. request

Tags: specific-reference, second-quantization

I am looking for the following paper in electronic format (I can get it in hard copy from my university library).

P. Jordan and E. Wigner, Z. Phys. 47, 631 (1928)

Does anyone know how to find it?

Comment: I don't think this is quite what the [tag:reference-request] tag is meant for... but while the community hashes it out I'll give you the benefit of the doubt and post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching [Inspire](http://inspirehep.net) for the authors' names or other identifying information will point you to the [journal server](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01331938) where you can download the article.